# what's full-text search solution on sql server 2008?

Tags: full-text-search

Is it possible to implement google style search on SQL server database on tables and columns? Some examples:
I have 5 tables with 25 columns(each has 5 columns), I want to the search can across different tables and columns in one query

as sql serverl full-text search only limit on one table, not sure what's the solution if want to search across tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full text search is great for searching one table. If you have two or three+ tables you could...

- **union your queries** (performance doubles every time you union)
- **refactor your database to one table**.
- **Create an index table** to query from, run t-sql every (x amount of min and repopulate your data from other tables)

If you don't have any authority to change the schema you could try [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/), [Lucene.net](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) or [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)